# Pyinstaller with Python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I want to compile my script to binary executable file in Linux using [Pyinstaller](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller/3.0), but the problem is [Pyinstaller](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller/3.0) compile with python 2.x instead of python 3.x. (build process success, but my script works only on python 2.x.).
Log:

> $ **pyinstaller script.py**
>
> 22 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.1.1
>
> 22 INFO: Python: **2.7.6**
>
> 22 INFO: Platform: Linux-4.2.0-34-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04
>
> ...

How can configure Pyinstaller to compile my script with Python 3.x.

---

I have solved my problem, use pip3 to install Pyinstaller:

```
sudo pip3 install pyinstaller
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: `pip3 install pyinstaller`? Use pip**3** to install pyinstaller.

Comment: Yes! it solved my problem. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install packages with pip for different versions you can use `pip3 / pip2 / pip2.7 / pip3.5 etc.` so in your case to get `pyinstaller` for python 3 just use:

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```